# Dash to Dock - initiate thumbnail preview with hover

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, ubuntu-dock

The default Ubuntu 18.04 `Dash-to-dock` dock allows a thumbnail preview of open windows for an application. You initiate this by hovering over the application and clicking once on it. There's no point requiring a click, and I'd rather the sequence initiate simply by hovering over the program (something Windows 7/10 actually gets right).

[This is already offered by `Dash-to-panel` as demonstrated here](https://github.com/home-sweet-gnome/dash-to-panel). But `Dash-to-panel` can't be placed on the left side of the screen where I need it. Only options for `Dash-to-panel` are bottom or top of screen.

How do I turn on this `Dash-to-dock` hover preview that I want?

Answer (score 6):

This is currently not possible as such in Dash to Dock. It would need to be implemented as a feature in future versions. It appears as if there is [work being done on this](https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/pull/574), so this may be implemented soon in a new version of Dash to Dock.